# Rewrite function to avoid overflow in numpy.exp

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following function:

```
import numpy, itertools    

def my_func(x):
        Z = 0
        for y in itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=10):
            Z += numpy.exp(numpy.dot(x,y))
        return numpy.log(Z)
```

The function works fine for input vectors that do not contain 'too extreme' values. However, if the input values are too extreme, at some point there will be overflow in the numpy.exp function. Here is an example:

```
x = numpy.random.normal(5, 10, 10)
my_func(x)
```

So far, the function works fine. However, if I substitute one element of x by an extreme value, I get the overflow error:

```
x[3] = 6000
my_func(x)
```

Is there a way to rewrite the function such that the overflow is avoided? I am aware where and why the overflow appears. Still, I can't find a way to rewrite the function to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy has [`np.logaddexp(x1, x2)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html), which computes `log(exp(x1) + exp(x2))`. So you could rewrite your loop as:

```
z = np.logaddexp(z, np.dot(x, y))
```

and skip the last call to `np.log`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been looking for!